# Azure Virtual Network. Connect VMs from different subnets

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I was wondering if it is possible to intercommunicate VMs in Azure within the same Virtual Network, but different on different subnets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subnets don't block traffic unless you define Network Security Group rules for blocking it. So yes, absolutely.