# Web Apps’ Access Restrictions Block Access to Subnets on the Virtual Network

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-webapps

We are utilizing Azure Web Apps' feature Access Restrictions. We restrict access and allow specific IPs and a subnet on our Virtual Network.
[image]

The problem is that only VMs that reside on that specific subnet are able to access the Web Apps, while VMs that reside on different subnets are not able to access the Web Apps [which doesn't make sense.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210999/azure-virtual-network-connect-vms-from-different-subnets)

Is such behavior is by counter-intuitive design or is it not working how it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ist Part--**

Yes, this behaviour is by counter-intuitive design. For your clear understanding the [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210999/azure-virtual-network-connect-vms-from-different-subnets) you are referring here Two Virtual Machine can intercommunicate from different subnet but they should reside in same VNET. It is by design you can follow this [MS document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-overview#virtual-network-and-subnets) For more information.

**Second Part –**

It is also by design , VMs that reside on that specific subnet are able to access the Web Apps and by setting up access restrictions, you have defined a priority-ordered allow/deny list that is IP addresses or Azure Virtual Network subnets.

When a request is made to your app, the FROM address is evaluated against the rules in your access restriction list. If the FROM address is in a subnet that's configured with service endpoints to Microsoft.Web, the source subnet is compared against the virtual network rules in your access restriction list. If the address isn't allowed access based on the rules in the list, the service replies with an [HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) status code.

Please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#manage-access-restriction-rules-in-the-portal) for more information.

Comment: So, we are not really allowing a subnet through Access Restrictions, bur rather IP ranges of that subnet. Thank you!